# Serialize classes in unity c#

Tags: unity, c#, mobile

Is there some best practices to serialize objects to file on mobile devices in Unity using C#. I've tried to search it myself, but found only this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Caching.html). However, it looks like here they are trying to cache `AssetBundles`. I'm new to `Unity`, but I have some experience in `iOS` (swift) development. Here we have opportunity to cache some objects(variables) in local storage, to avoid overusing network. So I wanted to create some static class (for example Storage), which caches variables to file permanently and return them by some key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity provides a way to save primitive values(`float`, `int`, `string`) by keys using the PlayerPrefs class.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

For more in depth serialization, like complex objects into a file(byte[]) for reloading later, you can use the `[Serializable]` annotation to do so.  Best practices found in the links below:
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/24/serialization-in-unity/
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html